# Graphic library for games and GUI

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, pygame

I want to make games with python, what is a good library for this? I can use Tkinter or Qt? Or pygame is better?
But for GUI applications(no games) i can use pygame or Tkinter/Qt is better?
Exist a library what is good for games and GUI applications?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For games is pygame the best.
For GUI is TKinter/Qt the right choice.

If you want to do both, you should use pygame.
Pygame is a really easy to learn SDL-Wrapper.
Also, it's possible to make GUIs with it (but its much harder then with TKinter/Qt).

AFAIK TKinter and Qt aren't able to "display" games.
*don't kill me, if I'm wrong*